# Rails pattern to build new object related to current view/model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newb question:  Say I'm currently viewing the `show.html` for one of my classes(`Dog`). This class has_many Flea(s).  If I put a "add new flea" link that links to `new_flea_path` (/fleas/new) when clicked it will build a new Flea (`@flea = Flea.new) and render flea's new.html.haml with its form fields...

But, how/where do I automatically pass in the dog_id that the flea needs to reference?

is this a routes issue? maybe `/dog/3/flea/new` is what I need to handle in routes?  or is this a controller thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is referred to as "Nested Resources". you can read up on them [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: OK, maybe this is source of my confusion. I'm familiar with nested resources (somewhat) but I've also heard (read) that you don't want to go more than 2 levels deep. So...what If I have a **city**, that has many **houses**, which each have many **dogs**, which each have many **fleas**??!? how is this handled...so the Rails gods don't laugh at me...!?! *(too late for that ;-)*

Comment: when you get into crazy nesting like that, your paths are going to shoot off the end of the screen, and your path helpers are going to be kind of silly (city_house_dog_flea_path(:city => @city, :house => @house, :dog => @dog, :flea => @flea)). This way of doing it doesn't scale that gracefully, which is why that recommendation is there. Thats the only reason though, so if you are fine with that then go for it.

Comment: what's the alternative? The "Rails way"?

Comment: @Meltemi: I'm not sure there is one (that is sort of a corner case) What I would do is come up with custom routes where it make sense, maybe 'location/:city_id/:house_id/flea/:dog_id/:flea_id' or something like that and make it a custom, named route.